# How to fix maven exception : [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.6.1:clean

Tags: java, maven

PFB full error log for command : mvn -U clean -

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.6.1:clean (default-clean) on project bDartCustom: Execution default-clean of goal org.apache.maven.plu
clean-plugin:2.6.1:clean failed: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.6.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact org.codehaus.pl
-utils:jar:1.1 in central (http://dummy_repo/repository/public) -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.6.1:clean (default-clean) on project bDartCustom: Exec
lt-clean of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.6.1:clean failed: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.6.1 or one of its dependencies could not be r
uld not find artifact org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:1.1 in central (http://dummy_repo/repository/public)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:309)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:194)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:955)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:497)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution default-clean of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.6.1:clean failed: Plugin org.apache.mave
aven-clean-plugin:2.6.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:1.1 in central (http://dummy_repo/rep
lic)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:309)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:194)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:955)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:497)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginResolutionException: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.6.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not
ct org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:1.1 in central (http://dummy_repo/repository/public)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.resolveInternal (DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.java:218)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.resolve (DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.java:149)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.createPluginRealm (DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:403)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.setupPluginRealm (DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:374)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.getPluginRealm (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:231)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:102)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:309)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:194)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:955)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:497)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Could not find artifact org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:1.1 in central (http://dummy_repo/reposit

```
at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve (DefaultArtifactResolver.java:422)
at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts (DefaultArtifactResolver.java:224)
at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveDependencies (DefaultRepositorySystem.java:338)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.resolveInternal (DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.java:210)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.resolve (DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.java:149)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.createPluginRealm (DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:403)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.setupPluginRealm (DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:374)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.getPluginRealm (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:231)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:102)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:208)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:309)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:194)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:107)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:955)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:497)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
```

Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactNotFoundException: Could not find artifact org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:1.1 in central (http://dummy_repo/repository/
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.ArtifactTransportListener.transferFailed (ArtifactTransportListener.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$TaskRunner.run (BasicRepositoryConnector.java:365)
    at org.eclipse.aether.util.concurrency.RunnableErrorForwarder$1.run (RunnableErrorForwarder.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$DirectExecutor.execute (BasicRepositoryConnector.java:583)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector.get (BasicRepositoryConnector.java:259)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.performDownloads (DefaultArtifactResolver.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve (DefaultArtifactResolver.java:399)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts (DefaultArtifactResolver.java:224)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveDependencies (DefaultRepositorySystem.java:338)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.resolveInternal (DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.resolve (DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.java:149)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.createPluginRealm (DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:403)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.setupPluginRealm (DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:374)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.getPluginRealm (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:231)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:102)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:309)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:194)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:955)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:497)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
[ERROR]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException

Comment: The simple issue here that you have configured to use an other repository which seemed to be not existing being used a central see: `Could not find artifact org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:1.1 in central (http://dummy_repo/reposit`. That means not all dependencies of the plugins can be found and so in the end Maven will not work cause it's needs plugins to work.. If you like to use Maven in a corporate environment you have to use a repository manager which proxies the access to Central...and there is no other practical options to work it...(manually downloading the deps?)...

Answer (score 0):

It seems you've configured a custom repository or proxy. (http://dummy_repo/repository/). When maven tries to find all required dependencies it does so by checking the configured repositories. If non are configured it will use maven central. Remove you custom repository and this will probably work.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but for security reason I need to put the custom repository / proxy. So, is there any other approach?

Comment: If that's the case then make sure that your custom repo / proxy is also proxying maven central or another repository that contains the above  jar, which it seems not todo right now. If you need this for security reason you might want to discuss this with somebody that manages or controls the proxy to make sure that you get what you need.

Comment: You may want to use a local Nexus (easy to run in Docker) to provide a combined view of Maven Central and your private repository.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that plexus-utils:jar is not in your repository. If you have permission in the repository you can check it.

Also, you could change your settings.xml to add a new repository which include the missing artifact.

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>org.codehaus</id>
        <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/codehaus/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

**EDIT**: The new URL of the old nexus.codehaus is https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/codehaus-snapshots/

Comment: Isn't repo1.maven.org Maven Central?